# Hard drive light constantly on, 'Working in background' cursor appears

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

Windows 10 Pro, Creator's Update installed. It's a fairly fresh install, only a couple months old.

PC has i7-4790k, 32GB RAM, 240GB M.2 SSD, and 2TB WD Black.

Here's the issue: The hard drive light is almost always on, only turning off for a split second every now and then. Occasionally the mouse with a spinner wheel appears. What is causing all this activity? I don't see anything using that much disk in Resource Monitor...

Comment: You could try `process monitor`

Comment: Explain that further

Comment: [process monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can show you all disk activity and which program is responsible for it.

Comment: Well, I got it downloaded but I've never used it before so I have no clue what I'm looking at. It appears that SearchIndexer is running, but killing it in Task Manager doesn't make disk activity stop. Disabling indexing doesn't do anything either

Comment: It helps if you turn off everything except "File System Activity" in process monitor.

Comment: Here's a screenshot https://pasteboard.co/GG6EfbB.png

Comment: What am I reading?